# What Sorts of Utlity Masks / Designs could I Incorporate into these Character Designs / Concepts?

Tags: clothing

---

This has more to do with character design than worldbuilding, but the character designs themselves will influence the worldbuilding, so I think it counts?????

I'm at the very early stages of creating some characters, and in turn, the very early stages of worldbuilding (I like to design characters first, and connect them to a world/story premise along the way). These characters' appearances are inspired by deep-sea fish and creatures, and I designed some masks that are loosely based on the fish's face/body structure

(Pictured: One of my first designs)

---

[image]

---

At first I gave the characters gasmasks, 'cuz I thought they'd be fun to draw, they come in several different forms/types, and I thought they could make for an interesting setting in terms of worldbuilding

The problem is:

- I'm having trouble incorporating gasmasks into a world that I'm actually interested in developing (An apocalyptic world is the obvious choice, but i just. dont wanna make an apocalyptic world)
- Gasmasks are actually a pain to draw. especially the filters, holy fuck

---

I still wanna incorporate masks into my designs, so I need mask ideas. Specifically:

- Types of masks that are used for utility, protection, and maybe entertainment/performance, too (gasmasks, oxygen masks, etc).
- (Purely aesthetic masks are fine too, but only for design inspiration,
  rather than anything that could influence worldbuilding.)
- Masks that can come in several different shapes and forms (often serving the same purpose, despite varying in structure, design, and sometimes time period. I.E., half face diving masks and full face diving masks)

Scuba/Diving masks are high on the list rn, as they actually connect with the fish-inspired character designs, and have several unique designs, but again, I'm having trouble incorporating them into a world setting. Still on the lookout!

Comment: What you intend to is world building, but please focus on one aspect of the masks at a time.

Comment: There are several unrelated questions here. Exactly what are you looking for? Is it a list of types of air masks, designs for them, different sea-creatures they might resemble, or reasons there are so many gas masks in your world?

Comment: I suggest you split this question into two or three more focused questions and resubmit.

Answer (score 2):

**Early Terraforming**

Your game is set on a newly terraformed planet. Part of the terraforming is making the atmosphere breathable. That part is not finished yet so the atmosphere has some fairly large proportion of XXX in it. Hence people wear oxygen-supplementing masks when outside.

There is a lot of freedom in this. For example an atmosphere like ours but with an extra XX% C02 is breathable but not good for your lungs in the long-term.

Answer (score 2):

**Put stuff in, keep stuff out:**

Basically, masks are to keep noxious things from getting into your lungs, or to put stuff you need into your lungs.

- **Darth Vader**: Your character needs purified oxygen to breathe due to some kind of respiratory damage.He might be breathing steroids to heal lung damage, or he could be breathing some super-gas that gives him superpowers. The options are open.
- **COVID**: Your character is diseased, and the viruses that infest him (or are helping him be powerful) are lethal to 80% of the people who come in contact with them. Super power/untouchable, or the character is Typhoid Mary. The best heroes are tortured. conversely, the world is filled with deadly plagues, and only a madman goes around without a face mask.
- **Industrial/steampunk**: Your world is deeply polluted. Factories pour out clouds of noxious chemicals and workers huddle in protected company housing, exploited. Only the bold are willing to risk benzene clouds and smokestack pollution so thick you can't see without special goggles.
- **WW1 trench warfare**:  Chemical weapons are rampant on the battlefields of your world, and leftover weapons are so prevalent that any criminal or terrorist can lay their hands on them. People go in fear everywhere, and take showers entering every building, just in case they've been exposed. Radiation applies equally here, as dust is readily contaminated.
- **Brave New World**: Your characters are explorers, and never know what they might encounter. New lands, new diseases, new weapons, New atmospheres.
- **20,000 Leagues under the Sea**: Your setting is underwater. Think diving helmets and breathing masks. Possibly living squid masks genetically designed to make breathable air from sea water.